# How to add a floating action button to WPF Desktop tool?

Tags: c#, wpf, floating-action-button

I'm coding a database tool to use as Windows Desktop Applikation. Im using C#, WPF and SQLite. How can I add a floating action button in front of the `ListView`?

Comment: Do you already have FAB?

Comment: Not already. Im new in wpf coding, so i only know some basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for positioning a button over another element there are various options, it depends on your use case what fits best. In this example, I nest a `DockPanel` inside a `Grid` that has two rows. The `ListView` in there spans both rows, while the `DockPanel` is in the second row.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding StringItems}"/>
   <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" LastChildFill="False">
      <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" Height="50" Content="-" Margin="5"/>
      <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" Height="50" Content="+" Margin="5"/>
   </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

If you look for a more Android looking button, you can use the [Material Design WPF library](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML) that offers different [button styles](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Button-Styles) for that purpose. See the [documentation](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Button-Styles#materialdesignfloatingactionbutton) on floating action button styles, e.g.:

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="-" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}"/>
```

This is how the result for both variants looks like.

[image: Floatings buttons.]

Comment: Uh, thanks. So easy, but i didn´t know that. this solution looks great